Fill Padding in a Scrollable Tab with Small System Font Size
I’m currently working on a Composable function that creates a scrollable tab. However, I’ve encountered an issue where the size of the items within the Scrollable Tab decreases when the system font size is set to small. This issue is particularly noticeable on certain devices, resulting in a significant amount of unused space at the right end of the tab.
I attempted to resolve this by adding weight inside the tab, but this approach was unsuccessful. I’m looking for a solution that would allow me to effectively utilize the free space that appears when the system font size is small.

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun CustomPager(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    data: List<TitleWithContent>,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    indicatorColor: Color
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val mPagerState = pagerState

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
            ScrollableTabRow(
                edgePadding = 0.dp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                selectedTabIndex = mPagerState.currentPage,
                indicator = { tabPositions ->
                    if (mPagerState.currentPage < tabPositions.size) {
                        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                            Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[mPagerState.currentPage]),
                            color = indicatorColor
                        )
                    }
                }) {
                AddTabs(coroutineScope, mPagerState, pagerData)
            }
        

        HorizontalPager(
            state = mPagerState,
        ) { index ->
            pagerData[index].content()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AddTabs(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    contentWithTitleList: List<TitleWithContent>,
    selectedContentColor: Color = ColorDark,
    unselectedContentColor: Color = ColorGray,
) {
    contentWithTitleList.forEachIndexed { index, page ->
        Tab(
            selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
            onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { pagerState.scrollToPage(index) } },
            text = {
                Text(
                    text = page.title,
                    style = if (pagerState.currentPage == index) AppTypography.current.selectedTabTitle else AppTypography.current.unselectedTabTitle
                )
            },
            selectedContentColor = selectedContentColor,
            unselectedContentColor = unselectedContentColor
        )
    }
}

data class TitleWithContent(
    var title: String,
    val content: @Composable () -> Unit
)


You can achieve the desired behaviour with a great approach. We need to create two tab rows i.e. TabRow and ScrollableTabRow. Now we show TabRow when the items are perfectly fit in the container width and if not prefectly fit then we show ScrollableTabRow. Makes sense right ?
We use onTextLayout lambda for the TextView to know were the text is perfectly fit or not. Here is the sample code for your use case.
// Tab items to show which are just strings
val tabItems = listOf(
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    //... other long headings,
)

// Our variable to keep track of the text is perfectly fit or not
var isOverflowed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// If the text is not overflowed then we show simple TabRow
AnimatedVisibility(!isOverflowed) {
    TabRow(
        //... requred paramteres
    ) {
        tabItems.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
            Tab(
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = tab,
                        softWrap = false, // Because we don't want text to cover more than one line
                        onTextLayout = {
                            // If the text overflowed then we change the variable
                            if (it.hasVisualOverflow)
                                isOverflowed = true
                        }
                    )
                },
                //... other parameters
            )
        }
    }
}

// If the text is not perfectly fit then we show Scrollable tab row
AnimatedVisibility(isOverflowed){
    ScrollableTabRow(
        //... requred paramteres
    ) {
        tabItems.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(text = tab) },
                //... other parameters,
            )
        }
    }
}

I have used AimatedVisibility here to add some smoothness but you can also just go with if-else if you want raw composition.
NOTE: I have just shared way to implement so please modify the code according to your needs and add required parameters properly.

This is actually good, but are there any option to remove that animation change, the user can easily notice this transition which looks a bit odd.

That also generates a similar effect. I am trying to see if there any solution for that, will update here if I find one.

@pepperlove Yes you can as I have also mentioned in the answer. You can just replace AnimatedVisibility with if-else branch means put ScrollableTabRow in if branch and normal TabRow in else branch while maintaining the same variable.

@pepperlove If then also the composition is visible then you can just change the type of variable isOverflowed with Boolean? instead of Boolean and then you have to compose nothing while the variable is null and if the variable has value then only compose ScrollableTabRow or normal TabRow based on conditions and this way it only compose once.
